# A macro with Sort Method of Range Class issue

Tags: vba, excel, sorting

I have a little problem with the macro below - I use data form to add or delete records. When I add a record, it works, but when I delete a record it doesn't work - the error comes up:

> "Error 1004 - Sort Method of Range Class failed"

```
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
    Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    SHEETS("STUDS").Visible = True
    SHEETS("STUDS").Select
    ActiveSheet.ShowDataForm
    Columns("A:H").Select
    Range("A1:H5").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, 
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    Range("A1").Select
    SHEETS("STUDS").Visible = xlVeryHidden
    Call sourceSheet.Activate
```

Can anyone help please ?

This is what came up highlighted as a problem:

```
Range("A1:G11").Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
```

Each time I add or delete a records, the Range changes, but macro code stay the same (A1:G11) - it does not change with Range

---

I have tried new and modified code but it doesn't work either

```
    Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
        Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    With Worksheets("STUDS")
        .Visible = True
        .ShowDataForm

        Dim LastRow As Long
        LastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in column A

        .Range("A1:H" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, 
        Header:=xlYes, _
        OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
        .Range("A1").Select 'only needed if you want to jump to the top
        .Visible = xlVeryHidden
    End With
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

The error msge was:

> The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort, and the first Sort by Box isn't the same or blank

(the first Sort By box is not the same or blank)
Pls help :)

Comment: You should probably know whether or not your data block has a header. Don't rely upon xlGuess.

Comment: You might want to read and follow: [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba) to speed up your code and make it less vulnerable to errors.

Comment: Thank you Jeeped - it worked. Just one more thing ... Each time I delete a record the Range changes, but the macro code stays the same covering the old range. Can you help to fix this too, please?

Comment: Thank you PEH ... it looks good so far .. as mentioned before, Range changes when record deleted. How to make macro so flexible that actual Range changes when record added or deleted ....

Comment: Actually it did not work again ... Worked fine when I deleted one record, but when I deleted another one - the same error came up. I see that the problem is that the Range changes when a record deleted but macro does not follow that change.

Comment: @Miles I meant you should read the link I gave you because using `.Select` is a bad practice and you should really avoid using them. You need to determine the last used row eg by `Dim LastRow As Long:    LastRow = Cells(Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row` which you can use in your range then `Range("A1:H"  & LastRow)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a way to avoid using `.Select` and finding the last used row to dynamically change the range.

```
Dim sourceSheet As Worksheet
Set sourceSheet = ActiveSheet

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With Worksheets("STUDS")
    .Visible = True
    .ShowDataForm

    Dim LastRow As Long
    LastRow = .Cells(.Cells.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row 'find last used row in column A

    .Range("A1:H" & LastRow).Sort Key1:=.Range("A1"), Order1:=xlAscending, Header:= _
        xlGuess, OrderCustom:=1, MatchCase:=False, _
        Orientation:=xlTopToBottom, _
        DataOption1:=xlSortNormal
    .Range("A1").Select 'only needed if you want to jump to the top
    .Visible = xlVeryHidden
End With
sourceSheet.Activate 'call is deprecated and not needed
Application.ScreenUpdating = True 'Don't forget to reactivate updating!
```

---

Please note that I used a `With` statement. This means everything starting with a dot refers to the worksheet specified in the `With` statement:

```
With Worksheets("STUDS")
    .Visible = True
    .Range("A1").Select
End With
```

is the same as

```
Worksheets("STUDS").Visible = True
Worksheets("STUDS").Range("A1").Select
```

You should always specify in which worksheet a range is. If you don't do this VBA assumes that the ActiveSheet was meant.

An alternative would be to define a variable for a sheet

```
Dim ws as Worksheet
Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("STUDS")

ws.Visible = True
ws.Range("A1").Select
```

Remember don't use `Range` without specifying in which worksheet the range is.

Comment: Thank you PEH .. I understood .. Now when I use your code and add or delete a record this is msge I've got: "The sort reference is not valid. Make sure that it's within the data you want to sort and the first sort by box isn't the same or blank" .       (it is not the same and it is not blank) .. I will update my post and show you the code ....

Comment: If your data has a header you key is probably `Key1:=.Range("A2")` instead of `A1`? And make sure you have a `.` before the range otherwise it does not reference the worksheet in the `with` statement! I can only insist in "*No `Range()` without referencing in which worksheet the range is*" If that doesn't change anything can you provide a sample data set that causes the error? I cannot reproduce it.

Comment: Furthermore when I add new record it sits outside the list (outside range) and I still get the msge: Sort method or range class failed - then I had to extend the list to be able to test again ...and again error .. Pls help

Comment: Ok - thank you ... I will try to change as per your suggestion and then, if no success will send you data sheet so u can reproduce ... Thanks hips PEH

Comment: Should be just the missing dot before `Range`. Both adding and deleting works perfectly with the code in my answer. Everything gets sorted.

Comment: Hi PEH - here is a link to the file -error happened when I added a couple (or three) records ...  https://1drv.ms/x/s!Av_nIf8pouuht2GrlexJQNN9BzO2       Please help if you can or if you have some time to spend on this - I am just stack :(.  Macro is assigned to the button in Sheet1

Comment: Please see the link .. Everything works while you add one or two records or when you delete one or two .. then the error comes up ... and my new added record sits outside List (and Range)

Comment: @Miles link is not valid! cannot download.

Comment: Sorry about that  .. not sure what could be the issue .. here is another one:    https://1drv.ms/f/s!Av_nIf8pouuht2LO9dSd77SDJ_f3       I have clicked on it and it works ...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/166688/discussion-between-miles-and-p).

Comment: PEH, you need to add https:// in front of the link to make it working. Let me know please if it is still the problem ...

Comment: @Miles of course I did that and I can access onedrive but it sais "document not available anymore" don't know why but got it working in a incognito window

Comment: It is past midnight here in Sydney .. I will have to leave our discussion now, but will try to resume tmrw morning or a/noon, depends on your availability. I am very thankful for your help, PEH. It means a lot ...  Kind regards

Comment: @Miles Which Excel version are you using? I guess the issue is that the `.ShowDataForm` interfers with your data *formatted as table*. So if I remove the *format as table* it works. Also if I extend the format as table by +1 row (so that it covers all your data) it works too in my Excel 2016

Comment: 2003 version ... well ... that could be the problem

Comment: Well probably that's it. 2003 is out of Microsoft's support since a while. Remove the format as table I suggest

Comment: Yeah .. I noticed... it works in 2003 too .. until I delete one or two records ..and then again, the same problem   My data is formatted like a List  I've had a problem to create it as a Table ...I could not sort out what to enter as Row input cell and what as a Column input cell ... Feel bad ...

Comment: 2003 is not very safe with the new format xlsx and xlsm. Not everything is compatible.

Comment: I could not sort out what to enter as Row input cell and what as a Column input cell ... So I entered my data as a List ....

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand your last comment. But if you remove the list and use just a normal worksheet it works as expected

Comment: OMG ... Yes, it works as on simple sheet ... what a solution ..Ha ... I feel crazy completely .. I know, it is not quite recommended working in excel 2003 but I have to as I am developing some kind of calculator/estimator and it has to work in all excel versions ... starting from 2003. Thank you so much PEH, I truly appreciate your help. Once again you are definitely a guy who can solve anything. Thank you!

Comment: Gladly we got this hard one solved finally. So please mark the question as solved, so no other people need to stick their heads into it.